# Displaying data from a sql query in a table via ajax in laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

I am trying to get data from a table using an ajax request. The query is successful, but the data does not appear in the table. It seems to me that the 'data' parameter of the 'success' function does not return any value.

this is the requisition:

```
 $('#btn_lista_proto').click(function(){
   
    var cod_cad = $('#hidden_id').val();
  
  $.ajax({
  
  url : '{{route('scr.lista_proto')}}',
  data:{'cod_cad':cod_cad},
  dataType:"json",


  success:function(data){
    
    table = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
        table += "<tr>";
        table += "<td>" + data.data[i].fk_documento + "</td>";
        table += "<td>" + data.data[i].protocolo + "</td>";
        table += "<td>" + data.data[i].data_registo + "</td>";
        table += "</tr>";
    }
    ;
    $('.display').html(table);

   }

   
  })
  
 });
```

This is the method in my controller

```
public function lista_proto (Request $request){
    

   $data = DB::table('protocolo_scr')
                ->join('secretaria', 'secretaria.id_scr', '=', 'protocolo_scr.fk_documento')
                ->select('protocolo_scr.*', 'secretaria.*')
                ->where('fk_documento', '=', $request->cod_cad)
                ->get();

         

     return response()->json(['success' => $data]);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
return response()->json(['data' => $data]);
```

Comment: If it helped then make it as accepted answer :-)